# No attachments in Searchkit

Tags: searchkit

Is there a possibility to view attachments in recent searchkit? I can't find a reference in entity dropdown. If it's not implemented, do you know where it would fit best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that EntityFile is not implemented yet in APIv4 ([see discussion here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25845)). There is File in APIv4, but that just gives you the file data without any connection to the entity it relates to.

You may want to comment on that PR to see if it can be moved forward.